# muliple versions of jquery are added in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

We need to either modify the existing product image code to load these images up and allow swipe through jQuery OR possibly embed an existing jQuery library to handle this. How can i add muliple versions of jquery in magento local.xml file?.

Answer (score 0):

You can add js files as follow in your `local.xml`

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>your/path/filename.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

If you are in a situation of adding multiple jQery, then you have to be very careful. Because lot of things are depending upon jQuery, system may behave differently, due to conflict between two version.